# Postgres in django app queries using PK UUID fields INT rather then the UUID

Tags: django, postgresql, django-contenttypes

Why is it that my model that has a UUID PK returns its INT representation during this lookup? This only happens on my dev server. Locally this works as desired.

```
class FooBar(models.Model):            
    foobar_id = models.UUIDField(      
        primary_key=True,                 
        default=uuid.uuid4,               
        editable=False                    
    ) 


self    
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x7f4cc8f98d30>
sql 
('SELECT DISTINCT "taggit_tag"."id", "taggit_tag"."name", '
 '"taggit_tag"."slug" FROM "taggit_tag" INNER JOIN "taggit_taggeditem" ON ( '
 '"taggit_tag"."id" = "taggit_taggeditem"."tag_id" ) WHERE '
 '("taggit_taggeditem"."object_id" = %s AND '
 '"taggit_taggeditem"."content_type_id" = %s)')
params  
(216053040644727963891633708661715513721, 9)



    Column     |           Type           |
---------------+--------------------------+
 exception_id  | uuid                     |
```

The resulting error:

```
operator does not exist: uuid = numeric
LINE 1: ..."tag_id" ) WHERE ("taggit_taggeditem"."object_id" = 21605304...
```

The lookup should be a `uuid` against another `uuid`. Not `numeric`. Don't understand where or why it gets converted.

```
class GenericTaggedItemBase(ItemBase):
    object_id = models.UUIDField(
        verbose_name=_('Object id'),
        db_index=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        primary_key=True,
        editable=False
    )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        verbose_name=_('Content type'),
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_tagged_items"
    )
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

Comment: Problem was that despite removing django-taggit from my requirements.txt file, it still gets installed as a dependency of django-taggit-serializer so my importing and updating of the package in my project made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model's PK might be a UUID, but the `object_id` field that's part of the GenericForeignKey field in TaggedItem is still an integer.

There wouldn't really be a good way of fixing this without modifying the taggit app itself, unfortunately.

Comment: I actually did import the taggit library into my own project and modified the GenericForeignKey to be UUID. I"ll post above. This works for me locally but when I deploy to my dev server I get this problem